# tween with function

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a movieclip which I want to transport from A to B with a tween. But what I want is while it is transported to be able to change some things in it's for example rotation. So what I want is, while it is transported to call an other function and dependent on which position my mc is, to make changes. How could I do that? Is there any way to check when a tween is completed, or when it is being performed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using a tweening engine like [TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/). These allow very easy tween setup and have properties you can set to handle mid-tween updates. Tweenlite, for example, offers the property onUpdate, which points to a function that gets run on every frame between the tween's start and finish. In your case, that's where you can check the MovieClip's position and set the rotation accordingly. A couple of the many other useful properties are onStart and onComplete, which are functions that get called at the corresponding times.

Answer (score 0):

I think the CasaLib Tween package is the most reliable and easy to use Tween code: http://as3.casalib.org/docs/org_casalib_transitions_Tween.html